# SyncProvider for new account are disabled by default

Tags: android, account

I recently wrote a new AccountProvider which has three SyncProviders attached for Android.

Account creation and everything else is working fine but whenever a user creates a new Account in Android the 3 SyncProviders are disabled. I think that changed but I don't know where I messed up the configuration.

I read the docs but found no option to give a SyncProvider an initial state. Can you give me a hint?

Any Code you need will gladly be postet as soon as I can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the code below and it worked for me.

```
ContentResolver.setIsSyncable(account, "com.your.package", 1);
ContentResolver.setSyncAutomatically(account, "com.your.package", true);
```